# Is it possible to ignore CodeDeploy deployment errors for deployments created using AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-cdk

I want to create CodeDeploy deployments using AWS CDK.  Currently, in the event that a deployment fails, the whole of the CDK stack is rolled back.  Is it possible to ignore any failures of the deployment?

For example, here is the output from the `cdk deploy` showing the rollback:

```
test-release-1: deploying...
test-release-1: creating CloudFormation changeset...
 0/5 | 00:34:43 | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::IAM::Role                   | test-release-1-CodeDeployRole (testrelease1CodeDeployRole533AAAB6)
 0/5 | 00:34:43 | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CodeDeploy::Application     | test-release-1-tls_proxy_ir (testrelease1tlsproxyir46F038FD)
 0/5 | 00:34:43 | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CDK::Metadata               | CDKMetadata
 0/5 | 00:34:44 | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::IAM::Role                   | test-release-1-CodeDeployRole (testrelease1CodeDeployRole533AAAB6) Resource creation Initiated
 0/5 | 00:34:44 | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CodeDeploy::Application     | test-release-1-tls_proxy_ir (testrelease1tlsproxyir46F038FD) Resource creation Initiated
 1/5 | 00:34:44 | CREATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::CodeDeploy::Application     | test-release-1-tls_proxy_ir (testrelease1tlsproxyir46F038FD)
 1/5 | 00:34:45 | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CDK::Metadata               | CDKMetadata Resource creation Initiated
 2/5 | 00:34:45 | CREATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::CDK::Metadata               | CDKMetadata
 3/5 | 00:35:00 | CREATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::IAM::Role                   | test-release-1-CodeDeployRole (testrelease1CodeDeployRole533AAAB6)
 3/5 | 00:35:03 | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup | test-release-1-tls_proxy_ir-cdk-test (testrelease1tlsproxyircdktest)
 3/5 | 00:35:03 | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup | test-release-1-tls_proxy_ir-cdk-test (testrelease1tlsproxyircdktest) Resource creation Initiated
 4/5 | 00:35:34 | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup | test-release-1-tls_proxy_ir-cdk-test (testrelease1tlsproxyircdktest) Deployment d-7MWZ2VBK1 failed. Status=Failed
        C:\Users\JOHN~1.TIP\AppData\Local\Temp\jsii-java-runtime8625275517600395680\jsii-runtime.js:7853:49
        \_ Kernel._wrapSandboxCode (C:\Users\JOHN~1.TIP\AppData\Local\Temp\jsii-java-runtime8625275517600395680\jsii-runtime.js:8313:20)
        \_ Kernel._create (C:\Users\JOHN~1.TIP\AppData\Local\Temp\jsii-java-runtime8625275517600395680\jsii-runtime.js:7853:26)
        \_ Kernel.create (C:\Users\JOHN~1.TIP\AppData\Local\Temp\jsii-java-runtime8625275517600395680\jsii-runtime.js:7600:21)
        \_ KernelHost.processRequest (C:\Users\JOHN~1.TIP\AppData\Local\Temp\jsii-java-runtime8625275517600395680\jsii-runtime.js:7388:28)
        \_ KernelHost.run (C:\Users\JOHN~1.TIP\AppData\Local\Temp\jsii-java-runtime8625275517600395680\jsii-runtime.js:7328:14)
        \_ Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\JOHN~1.TIP\AppData\Local\Temp\jsii-java-runtime8625275517600395680\jsii-runtime.js:7331:37)
        \_ processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
 4/5 | 00:35:35 | ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack       | test-release-1 The following resource(s) failed to create: [testrelease1tlsproxyircdktest]. . Rollback requested by user.
 4/5 | 00:35:43 | DELETE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CodeDeploy::Application     | test-release-1-tls_proxy_ir (testrelease1tlsproxyir46F038FD)
 4/5 | 00:35:43 | DELETE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CDK::Metadata               | CDKMetadata
 4/5 | 00:35:44 | DELETE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup | test-release-1-tls_proxy_ir-cdk-test (testrelease1tlsproxyircdktest)
 5/5 | 00:35:44 | DELETE_COMPLETE      | AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup | test-release-1-tls_proxy_ir-cdk-test (testrelease1tlsproxyircdktest)
 6/5 | 00:35:44 | DELETE_COMPLETE      | AWS::CodeDeploy::Application     | test-release-1-tls_proxy_ir (testrelease1tlsproxyir46F038FD)
 6/5 | 00:35:44 | DELETE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::IAM::Role                   | test-release-1-CodeDeployRole (testrelease1CodeDeployRole533AAAB6)
 7/5 | 00:35:44 | DELETE_COMPLETE      | AWS::CDK::Metadata               | CDKMetadata
 8/5 | 00:35:46 | DELETE_COMPLETE      | AWS::IAM::Role                   | test-release-1-CodeDeployRole (testrelease1CodeDeployRole533AAAB6)
 9/5 | 00:35:47 | ROLLBACK_COMPLETE    | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack       | test-release-1
```

In the event of a failed deployment, I just want the CDK stack to continue without error, i.e. no rollback.  Is this possible and how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an **open** GitHub **issue** for that feature in `AWS-CDK`:

- [Support RollbackOnFailure when stacks are created](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/2562)

So setting up the rollback behavior is not something that can be set in CDK for now. You can do it in CLI ([--disable-rollback or --rollback-configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/create-stack.html)) if this would be any help.

Comment: Thank you - not the answer I had hoped for, but thanks anyway!